# UIAlertController not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have an alert controller that is supposed to appear after a user enters an incorrect amount of characters in the text fields. The alert controller does not appear at all. W

```
func usernameFieldCharacters() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Five characters or more is required in all fields" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {

    action -> Void in // Does not do anything
    }

    alertController.addAction(okAction) // adds the OK button to 
    // to alert controller

    let allowedChars = 5 // character amount has to be equal or greater in each field
    let usernameCount = theUsernameField.text?.characters.count

    if usernameCount < allowedChars {
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        alertController.viewDidAppear(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not need the call `viewDidAppear` method first of all. Then check alertController presented in the **main thread**

Answer (score 2):

the code works correct, when u move the alertcontroller to i.e. viewDidAppear-method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let allowedChars = 5 // character amount has to be equal or greater in each field

    let usernameCount = theUsernameField.text?.characters.count

    if usernameCount < allowedChars {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Five characters or more is required in all fields" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {

            action -> Void in // Does not do anything
        }

        alertController.addAction(okAction) // adds the OK button to
        // to alert controller

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: It would be even better if all of the alert controller code was moved inside the `if` statement. Why create and setup the alert if it's not going to be shown?

Comment: And why do you think this codes need to be in `viewDidAppear:`? There's no reason for that.

Comment: @rmaddy no, you´re rigth, i didn´t know **why**. I found that, when i had a simular problem. The viewDidLoad seems to be to late...

Answer (score -2):

Above code works correctly. 
And alertController.viewDidAppear(false) is needn't